# RealTime data appending - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do something very basic in pandas and failing miserably.
From a high level I am taking ask_size data from my broker who passes the value to me on every tick update.
I can print out the last value easily enough.
All I am trying to do is append the next ask_size amount to the previous ask_size, to the end of a df in a new row, so I can do some historical analysis.

```
def getTickSize():
askSize_list = [] # empty list
askSize_list.append(float(ask_size)) # getting askSize and putting it in a list
datagrab = {'ask_size': askSize_list} # creating the single column and putting askSize in
df = pd.DataFrame(datagrab) # using a pd df
print(df.tail(10))
```

I am then calling the function in a different part of my script

However the output always only shows the last askSize:
askSize
0    30.0

And never actually appends the real-time data

Clearly I am doing something wrong, but I am at a loss to what.
I have also tried using the ignore_index=True in a second df, refencing the first, but no joy:

```
  askSize
0    30.0
1    30.0
```

I have also tried using 'for loops' but as there doesn't seem to be anything to iterate over (data is real-time) I came to a dead end
(note I will also eventually add a timestamp to each new ask_size as it is appended to the list. So only 2 columns, in the end)

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Where exactly does the `ask_size` variable come from? Is that defined outside the function?

Comment: Perhaps you should be declaring `df` as a global variable. My hunch is that you are creating new instances of `df` inside different function calls

Answer (score 1):

it seems you are creating a new dataframe, not appending new data.
You could, for example, create a new dataframe that will be appended to the existing data frame with the row(s) in the same format.

Lets say you have already *df* created. You want to add 1 new entry that will be read as a parameter (if you need more, specify more parameters), here is a basic example:

| 'askSize' |
| --- |
| 1.0 |
| 2.0 |

```
def append_row(newdata, dataframe):
    row = {'ask_size': [newdata]}
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame(row)
    # merge original dataframe with temp_df
    merged_df = pd.concat([dataframe, temp_df])
    return merged_df

df = append_row("5.1", df) # this will overwrite your original df
```

| 'askSize' |
| --- |
| 1.0 |
| 2.0 |
| 5.1 |

You would need to call the function to add a new row (for instance calling it from inside a loop or any other part of the code).
You can also use *df.append()* and other methods, here are some links that could be useful for your use case:

- [Merge, join, concatenate and compare (Pandas.pydata.org)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html)
- [Example of using pd.append() (Pandas.pydata.org)](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)

Comment: I suspect you are right, however when I put in the code the exact same thing happens. Only one row is added and changes in between calls. I have the function in the main code as you describe above and the function is called in the loop, along with the creation of the df:
while True:
         try:
       askSize_list = []
             askSize_list.append(float(ask_size))
             datagrab = {'ask_size': askSize_list}
             df = pd.DataFrame(datagrab)
             df = append_row(ask_size, df)
  
 except Exception as e:
         print(e)

Comment: Please verify what Ben Grossmann said above. It seems that you are creating the DataFrame each time that you try to append data and that will overwrite the older DataFrame.

Comment: @alejandro-aa. All solved. Called the old df with the new data in the loop;. And yes it looks like I was creating a new df in the loop, causing the issue